# unable to update specific values using Diff Util

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I have a app to shows a list of items. I need to update only the price textview of the item whenever the price get changed. But the whole list is getting updated in the recyclerview.

I'm using DiffUtil from this [Library](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter) In the below example, When `updateItems()` is called, I need to update only the `GRAPES Item` Price Textview to the latest price.

Please guide me....

**CODE**

**Fragment**

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;
final ArrayList<Indices> items = new ArrayList<>();
private RendererRecyclerViewAdapter mRecyclerViewAdapter;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    dashboardViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter();
    mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerRenderer(getYourViewBinder());
    mRecyclerViewAdapter.setDiffCallback(new DiffCallback());

    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(getItems());

    return root;
}

    private class DiffCallback extends DefaultDiffCallback<Indices> {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull final Indices oldItem, @NonNull final Indices newItem) {
        return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Indices oldItem, @NonNull Indices newItem) {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }
}

private ViewRenderer getYourViewBinder() {
    return new ViewRenderer<>(
            R.layout.item_futures, /* your item layout */
            Indices.class, /* your model class */
            (model, finder, payloads) -> finder
                    .setText(R.id.title, model.getName())
                    .find(R.id.tickerView, (ViewProvider<TickerView>) customView -> {
                        customView.setText(model.getPrice());
                    })
                    .setText(R.id.price, model.getPrice()));
}

public List<Indices> getItems() {
    items.add(new Indices(001, "APPLE", "15"));
    items.add(new Indices(002, "GRAPES", "50"));
    return items;
}

private void updateItems() {
    items.add(new Indices(001, "APPLE", "15"));
    items.add(new Indices(002, "GRAPES", "56"));
    mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(items);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.refresh) {
        updateItems();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class Indices implements ViewModel {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

@SerializedName("ltp")
@Expose
private String ltp;


@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return ltp;
}

public Indices(int id, String name, String price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.ltp = price;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Indices indices = (Indices) o;

    return id == indices.id &&
            Objects.equals(name, indices.name) &&
            Objects.equals(ltp, indices.ltp);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, ltp, id);
}

}
```

Comment: be sure that `equals` and `hashCode` work correct.

Comment: In areItemsTheSame, compare the old and new items by their ID not the price. Like this return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId()

Comment: @MohamedHamza I have edited it. But still it is not working...

Comment: @Vitaly I hope it works. It is generated by Android Studio. Any way to check it ?

Comment: try to call `items.clear()` before adding new elements inside `updateItems()` method